# Probability of collission for hash function that produces any possible 32 bit int?

Tags: hash, md5

I have a hash function that produces any possible 32 bit integer.

How do I compute the probability there's a collision, given X numbers already in the hash?

Comment: You'll need to provide more info about how the hash works. Without any more info, we can't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the hash function produces an effectively random-but-repeatable value (the goal of a cryptographic hash), then the chance of a collision when adding one not-yet-hashed number to X existing numbers is *X* in 2<sup>32</sup>.

For example, if the table is 50% full then you have a 50% chance of a collision, while if the table's 25% full you have a 25% chance of a collision.